# GET request URL getting duplicated in call from frontend

Tags: reactjs, api

I have an api and frontend I'm trying to connect.

The frontend and API are deployed on a kubernetes cluster. I'm calling a GET method to populate some data and the data is not being loaded from the api. I checked the method call from chrome and the API url is appended twice.

For example, a successful GET request to my API to load this data would be example.app.com/users and the url chrome is showing in debug for the GET request is example.app.com/example.app.com/users.

I verified the API GET method works and returns the data I need. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: could you please share the specific code snippet?

Comment: I'm not even sure what to share.. do you want to see where I'm calling the API uri? @NomanGul

Comment: we need to see a fully reproducible example to be able to troubleshoot the issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing "example.app.com/users" to the function that executes the GET API?
If you pass "/users", does the result work as you expect?

Comment: yep, I'm passing the full uri of the deployed api to the function. So instead of that, I should only try passing the end of the api route?

Comment: Yes. ”/users" to the function and run it.  Don't forget the slash.
I apologize for the confusion, but I was trying to give you a quick way to try it based on your text.